# The use of limit in Titchmarsh's book "The theory of the Riemann zeta-function" in Theorem $3.13$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

In Titchmarsh's book ["The theory of the Riemann Zeta-function"](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh_TheTheoryoftheRiemannZeta-Function.pdf) his Lemma $3.12$ is one of the main tools. Lemma $3.12$ is a version of Perron formula. Lemma $3.12$ starts by observing that, with $c>0$ and with $n<x$,

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^w \frac{\mathrm dw}{w}=1+
O\left( \frac{(x/n)^c}{T\log (x/n)} \right)
$$

This stems from the fact that $c>0$, and so if one completes the integration contour to the left by encircling the point $w=0$ completely in the complex $w$ plane by a rectangle whose right-most side is the original integration line $(c-iT,c+iT)$, the residue is simply $1$. This is the reason for the requirement $c>0$. The requirement $n<x$ comes from letting the left-most side of the integration rectangle be at $\Re(w)=-\infty$ and so $(x/n)^w\to 0$ if and only if $n<x$ as $\Re(w)\to -\infty$.

And so, in Theorem $3.13$ the starting point is the application of Lemma $3.12$,

$$
\sum\limits_{n<x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{c-iT}^{c+iT}
\frac{x^w \mathrm dw}{w\zeta(s+w)}+
O\left( \frac{x^c}{cT} \right)+
O\left( \frac{\log x}{T} \right)
$$

On the LHS the condition $n<x$ is the condition from Lemma $3.12$, and $c$ is still required to obey $c>0$.

Now Titchmarsh enlarges the contour of integration and encloses the $w=0$ completely, as earlier. Do notice that $c>0$ should still hold, since $c$ is nothing else but $\Re(w)$ on the right-most side the integration contour. No matter how the original line $(c-iT,c+iT)$ is deformed, the deformed closed integration contour must enclose the point $w=0$, and hence $c>0$ on the RHS part of the contour that intersects the real axis in $w$ plane.

With $c>0$ the pole at $w=0$ produces the residue $1/\zeta(s)$ and the result is now

$$\sum\limits_{n<x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}+O$$

The $O$ term tends to $0$ in the end, after Titchmarsh adjusts $T$ and $x$ appropriately.

And so then Titchmarsh requires

$$c=\frac{1}{\log x}$$

Additionally, he then lets $x\to\infty$.

But in this limit, $c\to 0$. And this makes the original starting equation useless, since the pole of the integrand at $w=0$ is no longer enclosed in the integration countour, but lies on the integration contour instead, if one interprets the limit as $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x=\infty$.

On the other hand, if one interprets the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x$ in the way that $x$ grows large but never hits the point at infinity, then $c$ never reaches $0$, and this would do. But aren't there problems with this interpretation of a limit in standard mathematics?

Maybe Titchmarsh uses the [Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem), but then the result misses the summand $\frac{1}{2\zeta(s)}$...

Or maybe I'm missing some detail completely here...

So my question is:

What exactly enables Titchmarsh to take the limit $x\to\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$; by the above (standard stuff you seem to agree with), there is a large enough half-integer $x(\epsilon)$ (depending on $s=1+it, \epsilon$), s.t. $|\sum\limits_{n<x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}-\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}| < \epsilon$ for any other half-integer $x \geq x(\epsilon)$ - as usual there is no restriction in using half-integers (i.e. $odd/2$) beacause the Dirichlet sum is constant between integers and the jump goes to zero since $s=1+it$

(choosing in Perron, $c=\frac{1}{\log x}, \log T= (\log x)^{\frac{1}{10}}, \delta = A(\log T)^{-9}=A(\log x)^{-\frac{9}{10}},x$, hence $T$ large enough, $A$ positive absolute constant coming from zero-free regions of $\zeta$)

But then the relation $|\sum\limits_{n<x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}-\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}| < \epsilon$ for $x>x(\epsilon)$ is precisely what is needed to conclude that the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$ of $\sum\limits_{n<x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ is precisely $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$, by the usual definition of limit.

So the point is that you apply Perron with large but finite $x$ and then in "shorthand" you let $x$ go to $\infty$ meaning the above $\epsilon - x(\epsilon)$ limit relation, which has nothing to do with making $x$ infinite as a number

Comment: Awesome, thank You, Conrad!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: $A$ is a constant that comes from the zero-free region - it probably has a value depending on an inferior bound on $x$ but not sure what is though if you allow large enough $x$ you can probably make it as big as you want (eg if you use $x >1000$ then the choice of $T$ gives  $T > T_0=(\log 1000)^{.01}$ and that gives a zero free region constant $A$ valid for those $T$). In general $A$ is irrelevant being just a constant that depends only on your intiial starting point but has no bearing on large values of $x,T$

Comment: @Conrad, what if we set $c = \eta + 1/\log(x)$ where $\eta$ is another small positive number. We will need to change $T = x$ So that all terms in RHS go to zero. And we don’t have to worry about $c$ going to zero. $\frac{x^c}{Tc} = \frac{x^{(\eta+1/\log(x))}}{ (x\eta+ x/\log(x))}$ goes to 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$ etc....

Comment: @shree the question makes sense only in the context of titchmarsh book as there is more going on and one needs to move the integral through the pole at $0$ coming from $1/w$ and still stay in a non zero area of zeta which is a function of $T$ so this determines $\delta(T)$ which in turn forces what $x$ can be in terms of $T$ etc; we then reverse engineer and get $T$ in terms of $x$ so they are not free parameters

Comment: @conrad, right, I am looking at theorems 3.12 and 3.13 for this and am interested in finding a way to keep contour away from $w = 0$ while also keeping $1/\zeta(s+w)$ also away from $0$ (iE $s = 1$ ) and also holomorphic in the whole contour. I was wondering what your thoughts may be on this arrangement. Putting an $\eta$ “stub” will keep it away, but then The expression for $T$ selected by Titchmarsh will stop working (the limit for first term diverge with revised arrangement). I think setting it to $x$ will recover from this issue. Any thoughts on what it might break?

Comment: In this case, $x^\delta$ can just be $T^\delta$ making the last term in RHS go to zero. ($-\delta$ being value of $w$ on the left side of the rectangle contour).

Comment: You’re knowledgeable about this (judging from other answers you have provided on this subject) I’m curious about whether you think there are any issues with this change.

Comment: @shree If you do not go through zero (make the power of $x$ negative) how do you control the integral $\int\limits_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac{x^w \mathrm dw}{w\zeta(s+w)}$? Remember you need to somehow extract the main term which is $1/{\zeta}$ and the difference must go to zero and for any $c>0$, however small, $|x^w| \ge 1$, while the denominator only integral gets estimated by $\log T \to \infty$. The whole point of this method is to go through zero to get a negative power in $x$ at the price of some resiue and the big issue is how far you can go

Comment: Although the contour does not go through $w = 0+i0$, the pole, it goes around it in a rectangle with sides $\Re (w)= c = \eta + 1/\log x, Im(w) = T = x, \Re(w) = -\delta, \Im(w) = -T = -x$. Residue is same. Eta and delta can take some values like 0.1.

Comment: All expressions on RHS go to $0$ with $x$ going to infinity (and $c$ Going to $\eta$ thus staying clearly on right side of pole).

Comment: @shree - that is the same idea then, sorry for misunderstanding what you wanted to say, but the point is that $T$ cannot be chosen arbitrarily since we only know a zero-free region to the left of the line that depends on $T$; in other words the $\delta$ to the left depends on $T$ and then if $x=T$, the $\log T$ term that comes from the new vertical integral overwhems the $x^{-\delta}$ so the estimate doen't work;

Comment: @shree do not forget the term $O(\frac{\log^8 T}{x^{\delta}})$ and the fact that $\delta$ is a function of $T$, namely the one used by Titchamrsh is $A\log^{-9} T$ for some absolute constant $A$, while the power $8$ comes from the estimates for $\zeta$ at the felt of the line

Comment: So if you do the computation, you need $A\log^{-9}T\log x$ to dominate $\log^9 T$ and that obviously doesn't happen for $x=T$

Comment: The last term becomes $O(\log^8 T/T^\delta) $ or $O(\log^8 x/x^\delta) $ which goes to 0 also. And $\delta $ can be any small  constant like $0.1$ making sure we stay clear of any zeroes of $\zeta(s+w)$ when $\Re(w)= -\delta $

Comment: sorry not a fan of chat; again $\delta$ depends on $T$ so if $x=T$, $x^\delta$ is not big but very small so no way it can overcome $\log^8 T$

Comment: $\delta$ constant doesn't work if you do not know a weak form of the Riemann Hypothesis ($\sigma < 1-\delta$ for the non-trivial zeroes and that is presumed to be as hard as RH itself)

Comment: Does it “have to” depend on T? I think it is fashioned that way so $x^\delta$ gets converted to $T^A$ thus driving last term to 0. But with $T = x$ that is already achieved.

Comment: For the integral to make sense you need to divide by $\zeta$ so you need to ensure that you do not pass through any zero, hence you need to stay in a zero free region and as noted the only ones known so far depend on $T$; I agree that the choice of $T$ is forced by the shape of the zero free region to make the estimates work, but again it is the shape of the zero free region (and to a lesser extent the estimates on $\zeta$) that are crucial

Comment: I got an impression that we have to be careful about choosing $\delta$ so the left side of rectangle doesn’t trip on a pole of $1/\zeta(s+w)$.

Comment: yes that is correct and Titchmarsh uses the zero free region $\sigma > 1-A\log^{-9} t$, so $\delta=A\log^{-9}T$ for a possibly smaller $A$ works

Comment: I suppose, small $\delta=0.1$ works if RH is true, but if RH is not true, $\delta= 1.1$ Is safer to stay clear of potential zeros in critical strip (that way when $\Re(w) =-1.1, \Re( s+w ) = -0.1$). $T$ should be chosen to not coincide with $t$ for Riemann zero.

Comment: The problem is that then you get lots of extra residues from the zeroes on the critical line for examples - the residue theorem includes the whole region swept by the rectangle so the bigger the $\delta$ the more zeroes you potentially include; the zeroes of $\zeta$ are isolated so choosing $T$ is no problem but choosing the rectangle so that no zero is inside it is THE problem

Comment: Thanks for your time and input. Please drop a comment if you think there is any other issue you can think of with revised choice for $c$ and $T$ or any other aspect of this.

Comment: Expressions on RHS:

Answer (score 2):

To see the idea of the proof, let $M(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)$ and we'll look instead at  $f(x) = \int_1^x M(y)dy$ to obtain absolutely convergent integrals.

Then Titchmarsh shows a lower [bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) $|\zeta(1+it)|\ge B/\log(2+| t|)$ plus an upper bound $|\zeta'(s)|\le B\log(2+| t|)$ to obtain some bound $|\zeta(s)|>1/(A\log(2+|t|)) ,|\frac1{\zeta(s)}|<\log(2+|t|)$ for $s=\sigma+it, \sigma\ge 1-\frac{1}{A\log^2(2+ |t|)}$.

And this is what we need to conclude $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}ds= \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\Re(s) = 1-\frac{1}{A\log^2 (2+|\Im(s)|)}} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} \frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}ds \\= O(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log (2+|t|)}{1+t^2 }x^{2-\frac{1}{A \log^2(1+ |t|)}}dt)\\ = 
O(\int_0^T \frac{x^{2-\frac{1}{A \log^2(1+ |T|)}}\log (2+|t|)}{1+t^2 }dt)+O(\int_T^\infty \frac{x^{2}\log T}{1+t^2 }dt)\\
=O(x^{2-\frac{1}{A \log^2(1+ |T|)}}) + O(\frac{x^2 \log T}{T})\\=O(x^{2-\frac{1}{A \log^2(1+ e^{\log^{1/4} x})}}) +O(\frac{x^2\log^{1/4} x}{e^{\log^{1/4} x}})=O(\frac{x^2}{e^{\log^{1/8} x}})=o(x)$$

If $M(x)> cx$ infinitely often, as $M(x+y)\ge M(x)-y$ then $|f(x+cx/2)-f(x) | \ge \sum_{n=0}^{cx/2} (cx-n) \ge x^2 c^2/8$ infinitely often, contradicting that $f(x)=o(x^2)$. Thus we proved $M(x)=o(x)$, the PNT.

Comment: An interesting proof of an equivalent of PNT, thanks! There's a typo at the end of the long equation, the end result is $o(x^2)$. It's all visible though, no problems here. Thanks again!